# How to enable copy/paste between an VMware workstation and a host

Tags: copy-paste, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I've an ESXi server that hosts multiples VM.
I'm using a CentOS 7 VM (not specific to this OS) and I'd like to copy/paste text between my host and the VM.

VMTools are installed and running properly on the VM but that functionality isn't working.

In the VMWare workstation application, there's only a limited nb of options available:

[image]

On the VM server side, the tools are installed and running:
[image]

Comment: this isn't programming related directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more time searching on this, I got it to work:

**Procedure**

1. Log into a vCenter Server system using the vSphere Client and select the virtual machine (**VM must be turned off** for the changes to be taken into account).
2. On the Summary tab, click **Edit Settings**.
3. Select **Options** > *Advanced* > **General** and click Configuration Parameters.
4. Click **Add Row** and type the following values in the Name and Value columns.
5. Start the VM

```
    isolation.tools.copy.disable     false
    isolation.tools.paste.disable    false
```

[image]

I find it surprising that such basic and common feature doesn't have some quick and easy access to toggle it ON/OFF.

VMWare [link](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.server_configclassic.doc_41/esx_server_config/security_deployments_and_recommendations/t_enable_copy_and_paste_operations_between_the_guest_operating_system_and_remote_console.html).